# Как спарсить с сайта электронные адреса используя findAll?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Хочу с помощью метода findAll извлечь из полученной простыни (Beautiful Soup) адреса электронной почты.  Подскажите пожалуйста класс, через который нужно искать ссылку?

[image: код страницы]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
mail_divs = soup.find_all('li', class_='mail')

for md in mail_divs:
    # print(md.find('a')['href'])
    print(md.find('a').text)
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Вариант через css-селектор:

```py
for a in soup.select('li.mail a[href]'):
    print(a.get_text(strip=True))
```